# Tutor LMS problem with Paid Memberships Pro

Tags: plugins

I am trying to Integrate Tutor LMS with Paid Memberships Pro. In Tutor LMS Content Settings, I am using option of full website membership. But problem is when a student becomes a member he still can not access the course.Course Enrollment page shows the message "You must have a membership plan to enrol in this course" even after buying the membership plan. I have confirmed that membership is successfully activated but student still can not enroll the course.

Comment: You'll have to ask the support teams of the plugins in question. [Third-party plugin support is off-topic here.](/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1):

I am from the Tutor LMS team. Please use the Help button our website to reach us. It is located at the bottom right corner. We will need to check your website configuration to find out and resolve the problem :)